# Build XML from a SQL Table with XPath and Attribute Values

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

I have to build a XML file by querying a database full of xpath entries
(ms sql) describing some configuration values (format is not changeable)

e.g. 3 columns, varchar

```
Path                            Attribute   Value
/configuration/options/startup  showSplash  1
/configuration/settings         idletime    1400
/configuration/options/defaults maxWindows  5
```

i started putting one xml together with c# code,
mergin overlapping pathes 
but then thought about doing that with sql.

```
<configuration>
  <options>
    <startup showSplash="1" />
    <defaults maxWindows="1" />
  </options>
  <settings idletime="1400" />
</configuration>
```

Is that possible - i did not find anything like that anywhere

Comment: How dynamic is this xml and data representation? and does this have to be done withing SQL server?

Comment: every xpath starts with configuration, but then anything can occur and variable depth - my first guess was to program it outside of sql server, which would be no problem at all.

I'd like to know if it is possible with a stored procedure for example (and not incredibly difficult)

Comment: while not impossible... doing this in tsql will be crazy difficult.  you'd be better of using SQL CLR if you want it returned from a view.  If it is a fix set of values you can write a replacement query but dynamically building an XML file based on paths like this is not what SQL was designed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a selection list from your original table which can be concatenated to into a dynamic select statement and finaly execute with sp_sqlexec.

I tried something like this.

```
DECLARE @strPaths VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlString NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT
    @strPaths
    =
    STUFF(
            (
                SELECT
                        ', ' + Value + ' [' + SUBSTRING([Path], 2, LEN([Path]) - 1) + '/@' + Attribute + ']'
                    FROM yourTable
                    ORDER BY [Path]
                    FOR XML PATH('')
            )
            ,1,2,''
        )

SET @sqlString = 'SELECT (SELECT ' + @strPaths + ' FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE) [XML]'

EXEC sp_sqlexec @sqlString
```

that returns the exact XML you are looking for

```
<configuration>
  <options>
    <defaults maxWindows="5" />
    <startup showSplash="1" />
  </options>
  <settings idletime="1400" />
</configuration>
```

but if I take out the 'ORDER BY [Path]'. The resulting XML is completely different.

```
<configuration>
  <options>
    <startup showSplash="1" />
  </options>
  <settings idletime="1400" />
  <options>
    <defaults maxWindows="5" />
  </options>
</configuration>
```

So you must be sure of the order of the paths in order to use a solution like this.

In conclusion: it can be done, only if you have an ordering criterion.

Comment: thank you so much,
i will try this out tomorrow and rank your answer

Comment: There was one minor issue, i had to put additional single quotation marks around the value.

seems to work perfectly